# Access internal resource from external ip

Tags: networking, ip-address, vnc

I have a network with a resource with an internal ip of 192.168.1.254 for example. I need to be able to access this resource from the external IP address of 86.126.1.234 let's say. I am off site and need to use VNC to access this computer.

How can I access this resource using just the two IP addresses.

Thanks in advance,
Maksim

Answer (score 0):

192.168. is a non routable ip address.
You need an external facing ip address.
to find out your external ip address you can try
whatsmyipaddress.com

You will probably need to change your router configuration to make your VNC port forwarded to 192.168.1.254.

Or, you if you just need remote control access to your Computer, try using 
www.teamviewer.com

Comment: Thanks for the help! Greatly appreciated.